# Python: Dictionary of Lists error

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have this code:

```
def PlayerStats(self,LSTPlayers,actualround):
   count = 0
   statDict = defaultdict(list)
   Stats = CStats.CStats('Cricket',self.Logs) #create instance
   statDict = Stats.WritetoDict()
   for objplayer in LSTPlayers:
       if Stats.FindPlayerIndex(statDict,"Player",objplayer.PlayerName) == -1: #if there is no player in the stats csv file
           self.Logs.Log("ERROR","Cannot find {} in the stats file!  I will add them.".format(objplayer.PlayerName))
           for key in statDict: count += 1
           self.Logs.Log("ERROR","Count of keys is: {}".format(count))
           statDict[count+1].append(objplayer.PlayerName,objplayer.GetTotalTouch,actualround,Stats.MPR(objplayer.PlayerName))
       else:
           self.Logs.Log("DEBUG","Updating {}'s stats!".format(objplayer.PlayerName))
```

And i keep getting the error: IndexError: list assignment index out of range.

in line 5, statDict is being updated with a defaultdict(list) from another class that reads a csv file and returns the dictionary of lists.

Line 7 looks for the player name in the dictionary, which if it doesn't find, returns -1, otherwise returns index of player.

I was looking to add a new list to the dictionary of lists with information if the player wasn't in there already.

Update-- Here is my code for the writetodict fuction in CStats file:

```
def WritetoDict(self):
    with open(self.pathfile) as f:
        self.PlayerStatDict = [{k: str(v) for k, v in row.items()}
            for row in csv.DictReader(f, skipinitialspace=True)]
    return self.PlayerStatDict
```

PlayerStatDict is defined as a defaultdict(list) in the CStats file.

Comment: Can you post full stack traceback?

Comment: What does `WritetoDict` returns? List?

Comment: Your error (as you can see it for yourself) is occurring due to assignment of value to non-existing index in a list. This code doesn't contain line where you assign value to index.